# visual studio access to path is denied - multiple drives

Tags: visual-studio-2010, permission-denied

Just installed vs2010 on a windows 2008 server and tried running an application that accesses one of the drives and got the error

```
access to the path E:\logfiles is denied.
```

I am logged in as an administrator and I see visual studio is being run as administrator.

Is there any specific permissions I need to set or is it something else.

I doubt it's my code since it ran fine on my desktop using visual studio 2008

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this error while trying to save changes on a RDL file in a Report Project in VS2008. The solution for me was to check the properties dialog of the project folder in the file system and uncheck the "Read-only" checkbox in the "Attributes" section.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be checking permissions on E:\logfiles.
Running an application through the debugger in VS *could* mean the application is running under a different user account that doesn't have permission to access that location (I emphasize *could* , I'm really not sure). Try navigating to the .exe in the bin/debug or bin/release directory of your project and run the application as administrator from there.

Comment: I checked the permissions on the folder and even tried just using the C:\ root. I am about to just resort back to studio 2008 but not sure if it visual studio or issue or windows server 2008 R2 issue. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked the "read-only" option on the wwwroot and it helped me.